# CASE WHEN THEN ELSE change to union?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, case-expression

I was wondering if it is possible to change a `CASE when then else` to a `union all`, or something like this.

I hope that it is possible ...

example

```
CASE WHEN(C.Salutation = 'Dhr.' OR C.salutation = 'dhr.')
         THEN 'Meneer'+' '+ISNULL(C.middlename+' ','')+C.Lastname
    WHEN(C.Salutation = 'Mw.' OR C.salutation = 'mw.')
         THEN 'Mevrouw'+' '+ISNULL(C.middlename+' ','')+C.Lastname
    ELSE 'Meneer/Mevrouw '+ISNULL(C.middlename+' ','')+ISNULL(C.Lastname,'') END AS 'K5'
```

i hope you guys can help me out..

Comment: Whould it make sence? CASE is just what you need here

Comment: yeah but the man i'm doing this for want it in a diffrent way..
but i,ve google it and i can find something...

Comment: If this is being used as part of the SELECT (not part of the WHERE) then CASE is the best way to do this. It would be worth pushing back on the man you're doing this for and suggesting it stay this way.  However Scorpi0 has the correct answer shown.

Comment: thanks i should tell him this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes you can, but it is ugly:

```
SELECT 'Meneer'+' '+ISNULL(C1.middlename+' ','')+C1.Lastname AS 'K5'
FROM table C1
WHERE C1.Salutation = 'Dhr.' OR C1.salutation = 'dhr.'
UNION
SELECT 'Mevrouw'+' '+ISNULL(C2.middlename+' ','')+C2.Lastname
FROM table C2
WHERE C2.Salutation = 'Mw.' OR C2.salutation = 'mw.'
UNION
SELECT 'Meneer/Mevrouw '+ISNULL(C.middlename+' ','')+ISNULL(C.Lastname,'')
FROM table C3
WHERE C3.Salutation != 'Mw.' AND C3.salutation != 'mw.'
AND C3.Salutation != 'Dhr.' AND C3.salutation != 'dhr.'
```

Comment: @Jeroen Note though that just 'UNION' will return only unique rows. If you want to see duplicates as well you should use 'UNION ALL'

Comment: i know now i am using UNION ALL